# json escape characters with back and forward slash

Tags: json, escaping

A part of my json schema is coming off with backward and forward slash after serialization.

My question is, is this a valid encoding? I'm having issues with the api too for some reason, so trying to see where the problem is.

```
"_links": {
    "altAssetUrl": {
        "href": "\/publication\/d40a4e4c-d6a3-45ae-98b3-924b31d8712a\/altasset\/48baad57-81a5-4d32-a2a1-e52c5cbe964d\/"
    },
    "contentUrl": {
        "href": "\/publication\/d40a4e4c-d6a3-45ae-98b3-924b31d8712a\/article\/test\/contents;contentVersion=1521071354969\/"
    }
},
```

In another area I noticed special characters %2F etc.

```
"socialShareUrl": "https:\/\/example.com\/ssp?entityRef=%2Fpublication%2Fd40a4e4c-d6a3-45ae-98b3-924b31d8712a%2Farticle%2Ftest",
```

Please advise on what can I do to fix this escaping of slashes, I'm using .net language.

Comment: what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is this a valid encoding?

Yes.

```js
var json = '"This has a slash\\/"';
console.log("Raw JSON: " + json);
var str = JSON.parse(json);
console.log("String result of parsing JSON: " + str);
```

> In another area I noticed special characters %2F etc.

Perfectly normal URL encoding.

Comment: maybe the api at server end is not used to seeing this, and my http requests are ended up as broken pipes, not sure what's wrong and where

Comment: can you upvote my question, I don't know why people down vote without any reason or explanation